# How to check checkbox based on row table (database)?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I've a form that can edit/update data build in modal (bootstrap), I want to check the checkbox based on my row table...

this is my edit/update form :

```
<td><fieldset id="menu_e">
<input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="User" class="ceksmenu">User<br />
<fieldset id="sub_menu_user_e">
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="User1" class="ceksmuser">User1
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="User2" class="ceksmuser">User2
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_user" value="User3" class="ceksmuser">User3<br />
</fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="Monitoring" class="ceksmenu">Monitoring<br />
<fieldset id="sub_menu_monitoring_e">
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="Monitoring1" class="ceksmmonit">Monitoring1
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="Monitoring2" class="ceksmmonit">Monitoring2
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_monitoring" value="Monitoring3" class="ceksmmonit">Monitoring3<br />
</fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="Parameter" class="ceksmenu">Parameter<br />
<fieldset id="sub_menu_parameter_e">
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="Parameter1" class="ceksmparam">Parameter1
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="Parameter2" class="ceksmparam">Parameter2
<input type="checkbox" name="sub_menu_parameter" value="Parameter3" class="ceksmparam">Parameter3</fieldset>
</fieldset>
</td>
```

this is my table code :

```
<tbody>
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${requestScope.authorityuser}">
      <tr>
          <td>${row.id_authority}</td>
          <td>${row.nama_authority}</td>
          <td><c:forEach var="u" items="${row.menu}">|${u}| </c:forEach></td>
          <td><c:forEach var="u" items="${row.sub_menu_user}">|${u}| </c:forEach></td>
          <td><c:forEach var="u" items="${row.sub_menu_monitoring}">|${u}| </c:forEach></td>
          <td><c:forEach var="u" items="${row.sub_menu_parameter}">|${u}| </c:forEach></td>
          <input type="hidden" name="id_authority" value="${row.id_authority }">
          <td><a href="#update" role="button" data-toggle="modal"
             class="update" id_update="${row.id_authority}"
                        nama_authority="${row.nama_authority}" menu="${row.menu}" 
                                sub_menu_user="${row.sub_menu_user}" sub_menu_monitoring="${row.sub_menu_monitoring}" 
                                    sub_menu_parameter="${row.sub_menu_parameter}"> <i class="icon-edit"></i> <spring:message code="edit" text="default text" />
              </a><a href="#delete" role="button" data-toggle="modal"
                                class="delete" id_delete="${row.id_authority}">
                                 <i class="icon-trash"></i> <spring:message code="delete" text="default text" />
                            </a></td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
```

I tried like this and it's not work :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.update').click(function() {
       if($('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_user]').is(':checked')){
           $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_user]').prop('checked', true);
      }else{
           $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_user]').prop('checked', false);
      }
     var id_update = $(this).attr("id_update");
     var nama_authority = $(this).attr("nama_authority");
     var menu = $('input:checkbox[name=menu]').is(':checked');
     var sub_menu_user = $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_user]').is(':checked');
     var sub_menu_monitoring = $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_monitoring]').is(':checked');
     var sub_menu_parameter = $('input:checkbox[name=sub_menu_parameter]').is(':checked');

     $('#id_authority_e').val(id_update);
     $('#id_authority_l').val(id_update);
     $('#nama_authority_e').val(nama_authority);
     $('#menu_e').val(menu);
     $('#sub_menu_user_e').val(sub_menu_user);
     $('#sub_menu_monitoring_e').val(sub_menu_monitoring);
     $('#sub_menu_parameter_e').val(sub_menu_parameter);
  });
  $('.delete').click(function() {
     var id_delete = $(this).attr("id_delete");
     $('#id_authority_d').val(id_delete);
  });
     $('#example').dataTable({
  });
});
</script>
```

this is the output of my table

[image]

how is it possible?? any help will be pleasure :)

this is my edit/update form

[image]

this is my table

[image]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is the result vs expected result?

Comment: @winner_joiner what I expected is when I open edit/update form the checkbox was check based on value of my row table (database)...but the result I get is when I open the edit/update form the checkbox is still unchecked although that I still can update the data, any idea

Comment: i dont know much about the Java-Template. But now your javascript code is checking if the checkboxes are already checked(but they wont be since the page has just been opened). you would have to read the values out of the table, or hiddenfields, or pass somehow other the values ...

Comment: @winner_joiner hmm, if you see "my table code" in my post...I get the all value from that.. how my javascript can get that value and make my checkbox checked, any idea??

Comment: since i am not fit with jsp, can you post the resulting(rendered) html from the Table and i could suggest a way. Since for example i dont know what html, will be generated for this line, `<td><c:forEach var="u" items="${row.sub_menu_user}">|${u}| </c:forEach></td>`

Comment: @winner_joiner i've add my table in my post... hope you can help me :)

Comment: have you already a working solution? Or do you need still some help.

Comment: @winner_joiner not yet dude, I got stuck to give condition to check the checkbox :/

Comment: I updated the Code, I hope it helps... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i just looked at the javascript portion, here is my answer.

You would have to read the Text in the HTML and parse it, for that you need to be able to get a specific cell. With the ***row_id***  you can narrow your search down and over the ***classname*** for the cloumn you get the right cell.

I hope this short working demo on **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfcFL/1/)** might help you with your "problem".

**HTML:**

```
<table class="data-table">
    <tr id="row_1"><td class="authority">...</td> 
        <!-- id should be constructed something like id="row_${row.id_authority}" -->
        <td class="...">...</td>
        <td class="users">|user1|user2|user3|</td>
        <td class="...">...</td>
        <td> <a href="#update" class="update" id_update="1">edit</a>  </td>
        <!-- id_update should be as in your code id="${row.id_authority}" -->
    </tr>  
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".update").click(function(){
        var id_update = $(this).attr("id_update");
        var users = $("#row_" +  id_update).find(".users").text().split("|").slice(1,-1);
        for(var user in users)
            alert(users[user]);
    });
});
// tested on Windows 7 with Chrome 33+
```

***edit: added some "Code"***

**possible JSP Code:**

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${requestScope.authorityuser}">
    <tr id="row_${row.id_authority}">
        <td class="...">${row.id_authority}</td>
        <td class="...">...</td>
        <td class="users"><c:forEach var="u" items="${row.sub_menu_user}">|${u}| </c:forEach></td>
        <td class="...">...</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#update" role="button" data-toggle="modal"
            class="update" id_update="${row.id_authority}"
            nama_authority="${row.nama_authority}" menu="${row.menu}" 
            sub_menu_user="${row.sub_menu_user}" sub_menu_monitoring="${row.sub_menu_monitoring}" 
                sub_menu_parameter="${row.sub_menu_parameter}"> <i class="icon-edit"></i> <spring:message code="edit" text="default text" />
            </a> ...
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

***edit:***

i updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfcFL/2/) (this link is different to the one above).

the important part is here...

```
for(var user in users){
    // it could be optimized, but like this it could work.
    $("input[name='sub_menu_user'][value='" + users[user] + "']")[0].checked=true;
}
// tested on Windows 7 with Chrome 33+
```

Comment: okehh, that give me some clue... FYI: the value of this out put ~> "|user1|user2|..." is an Array that I split before, can I do what you suggest to me??

Comment: i posted some jsp - "code", i hope this helps. Do you need somemore pointers?

Comment: I'm very appreciate that everything you told to me... but I've try your scripts and does not work on me... the checkbox still not checked and that affect the 2 textbox (id_authority and nama_authority) that can get the value after I add your script to my jsp, what should I do? :/

Comment: @splatter_fadli Okay lets see if we can fix this. :) I have some questions, does the new jsfiddle demo work on your computer? Which browser are you using and on which browsers should this page work? Can you see Javasscript errors when running the code? And last question can you post the generated html from the screenshot and from the edit form (right click the website , view source code `just the part from the table and the edit-form`)

Comment: yeah, your jsfiddle work on my computer, I'm using Chrome, I've edit my post, hope can help :)

Comment: Hi dude, do you have any idea?? I still got stuck :|

Comment: Was i week on a businesstrip, will look at it tonight, i didnt forget :) (CET)

Comment: nevermind dude, I have find the solution of my problem.. I just give some little modification of your scripts and voilaaaa :)... you are such a nice guy dude, tha-nks :)